# Efficent Algorithm to Answer Subarray Queries fast

Tags: c++, algorithm

The other day I encountered a problem related with queries, but I can't solve it.

Given an array with *N* integers and a positive integer *M*, you must answer *Q* queries. Each query is characterized as ( *i* , *j* ), where *i* and *j* are each indices of the array. In each query you must answer how many pairs ( *r* , *s* ) exist such that

1. *i* <= *r* <= *s* <= *j*
2. the sum of the array elements with indices in [ *r* , *s* ] is divisible by M.

Limits:

```
N <= 50,000
Q <= 50,000
M <= 100
```

I have a dynamic programming solution that preprocesses every query ( *r* , *s* ) in O( *N*^2 ), but that is not fast enough. Is there a more efficient solution? I have some ideas with Mo's algorithm, or with segment trees, but I can't get it.

Comment: Sort the array first (logarithmic complexity). Now the subrange (i,j) can be found with a binary search. To compute for a given (i,j), precompute all values in the range modulus M, and how many of each value [0,M) occurs. Based on the count of each, the number of possible pairs can be trivially computed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, `(i, j)` are indices of the array, not values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Calculate the prefix sums of the original array (assuming it's 1-based) for every `i = 1..N`.
   [image]
   The equivalence of `Sum[r]` and `Sum[s]` for any two indices `r` and `s` where `r < s` means that the sum of the array elements with indices in `[r+1, s]` is divisible by `M` (and we need to calculate the number of such equivalences within interval). The time complexity of this step is `O(N)`.
2. Precalculate the array `Count` for every `i = 1..N, j = 0..M-1`: 
   [image]
   `Count[i][j]` stores the number of times that `Sum[len]` (where `len <= i`) was  equal to `j`. Time complexity of this step is `O(N*M)`.
3. For every query `(i, j)` the answer will be equal to:
   [image]
   For every possible value of the remainder `k` we find `D(k)` - the number of times that `Sum[len]` is equal to `k` within interval `[i, j]`. Then we add to the result the number of all possible pairs of `D(k)` interval boundaries that is `D(k)*(D(k)-1)/2`. Time complexity: `O(M)` for every query.

**Complexity**: `O(N) + O(N*M) + O(Q*M) = O((Q+N)*M)`, that would be ok for given constraints.

Answer (score 1):

First note that for any subarray `(r, s)` that sums to a multiple of `M`:

```
sum(r, s) == sum(i, s) - sum(i, r - 1)

          == (qa * M + ra) - (qb * M + rb)
```

where `ra` and `rb` are both less than `M` and greater than or equal to `0` (*i.e.* the respective remainders after dividing by `M`).

Now `sum(r, s)` is divisible by `M` so it's remainder is `0` after dividing by `M`.  Therefore:

```
ra == rb
```

If we calculate all the remainders after dividing the sums the subarrays `(i, i)`, `(i, i + 1)`, ... ,`(i, j)` by `M` as `r1`, `r2`, ... , `rj` then store the count of all these in an array `R` of size `M` so that `R[k]` is the number of remainders equal to `k`, then:

```
R[0] == the number of subarrays starting at i that are divisible by M
```

and for every `k >= 0` and `k < M` such that `R[k] > 1` we can count `R[k]` choose `2`:

```
(R[k] * (R[k] - 1)) / 2
```

subarrays not starting at `i` that are divisible by `M`.

Creating and summing all these values gives us the answer in O( N + M ) for each `(r, s)` query.

Comment: Why the complexity is `O(Q+M)`? May be `O(Q*M)`?

Comment: @DAle It takes Q steps to loop from `i` to `j` computing the next accumulation of the running sum, the remainder at that point, and updating `R`. Then M steps to loop through `R` updating the total at each step for O( Q + M )

Comment: `Q` is the number of queries.

Comment: @DAle Ah, you're total correct! Updated answer - thanks. OP has O( N^2 ) per query - this is O ( N + M ) per query.